# Why getting the `This page isn't working... ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`?

Tags: java, angular, maven, angular-cli, maven-plugin

Generated same script file with multiple times in index.html file, I recently upgraded project to angular 8.0.2 version

After upgrading the angular version, am getting this replication problem in `index.html` file.

> This is `JavaDemoProject` java project, i run the angular application with this `javaproject` with the help of `pom.xml` file
>
> I build the project through maven command(`mvn clean install -Penv-dev -DskipTests -DbuildNumber=04`)

- `pom.xml` file

  ```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.testDemo</groupId>
      <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>../Angular-Project</workingDirectory>
          <installDirectory>temp</installDirectory>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
         <!-- It will install nodejs and yarn -->
         <execution>
             <id>install node and yarn</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <nodeVersion>v11.7.0</nodeVersion>
                 <yarnVersion>v1.9.4</yarnVersion>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
         <!-- It will execute command "yarn install" inside "/angular" 
              directory -->
         <execution>
            <id>yarn install</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
         <!-- It will execute command "yarn build" inside "/angular" 
             directory to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
         <execution>
             <id>yarn javaDemoprod </id>
             <goals>
                <goal>yarn</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <arguments>javaDemoprod --outputPath=../JavaDemoProject/
                    src/main/resources/templates/dist</arguments>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```
- `tsconfig.json` file:

  ```
  {
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
           "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
           "es2017",
           "dom"
        ],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
  }
  ```
- This is the `angular.json` file:

  ```
  "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/Angular-Project",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "showCircularDependencies": false,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/eg.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "aot": true
      }
    }
  ```
- Package.json

  ```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-scss-preprocessor": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
  ```

> After build the application in `index.html` path of the 
>    file `JavaDemoProject\src\main\resources\templates\dist\index.html` am getting this replication of `script` files, how can i prevent this replicate `script` files.

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule></script>
</body>
```

> This replications of script file am getting the output of the application showing

```
This page isn't working...
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts which you are able to see is because of the differential loading feature.
Angular 8 has a new feature to generate a separate bundle to the older browser and new browsers. 
You can control which browser you want to support, you can read more about this feature on 
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information @SantoshYadav, but i did the same changes in my code then also am getting the same `This page isn't working...`.

Comment: can you share the stackblitz or github repo to check with the minimum config?

Comment: stackblitz link: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxxjhu), if I run the ``angular project(for Mobile version)`` separately, it showing the `home page` and working throughout the application fine. In my case we deploying along  with ``desktop(JAVA)`` site, based on the screen size we are showing desktop/Mobile. After build and deploy the application desktop working fine, when we are open in the Mobile screen, Angular project is not getting, It showing `This page isn't working... ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, I delete the all browser's history & cookies, then also am getting the same.

Comment: In `logs` file showing `ERROR Error occurred while processing the request : Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="/dist/index", for the URI : /flights, visitorId : null, searchKey : null, IP Address : localhost, REQUEST METHOD : GET
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="/dist/index"`. thymeleaf unable to read the `nomodule`. How can I solve this ?